# squid.confに環境変数を適用するには？

Tags: amazon-ec2, squid

現在、AWS　EC2上でsquidを用いたプロキシサーバーを構築しているのですが、

squidの設定ファイルであるsquid.confの中身の一部に、
環境変数をどのようにすれば反映させることができるでしょうか。